# Mixing .c and .h files

Tags: c, header-files

I have seen C programs split into `.h` files with its respective `.c` files.

I know that header files are for macros/declarations/function prototypes and .c files for function definition.

But how are those `.c` got used ? passed by compiler's command line?

Comment: Please read your question carefully and ask yourself - can this reasonably be answered without further information/background? Do you know how a `makefile` is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C files are not combined by the compiler, but by the [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29).  Depending on how you compile your code this may be hidden from you.

The compiler will compile each of the C files into an [object file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) for each C file.  Then the linker will take these object files and combine them into an executable file or a library file.

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

- Pass the `.c` files to the compiler's command line, all together, for a "compile and link all in one" command. You usually only do that for toy and very small projects
- compile each `.c` file individually (giving it as a separate compile command line), generating `.o` files. Then passing all these `.o` files together to the linker (normally it's the same command as the compiler...) to create your executable. This way if you change a `.c` file you only have to compile that file (to create its `.o` file again) and link, saving a lot of time.

Comment: And option 3, use `make` or a similar system to orchestrate the compilation for you (noting that it will adopt option 2 for the work it does).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `make` just runs the commands for you. For that matter you could just answer "give the files to someone who knows how to do it". It teaches nothing. Also, you have to write the `Makefile`.